# Swift, Pass the Array in popover controller and send it back to the controller

Tags: ios, swift, uipopovercontroller

I am developeing Listing page with map and i have popover for sorting the array in swift. How can i pass the array in popover controller? and after sorting how do i give it back?

### My code below for the popover controller

```
  func sortingPressed(sender: AnyObject){

   var sortingPopView = SortingPopoverController(nibName: "PopView",bundle: nil )

     var sortingPopoverController = UIPopoverController(contentViewController: sortingPopView)

     sortingPopoverController.popoverContentSize = CGSize(width: 250, height: 100)
                             sortingPopoverController.presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem(self.navigationItem.rig     htBarButtonItem!, permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirection.Any
        , animated: true)

    }
```

THanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Since UIPopoverController extend NSObject to pass array (or any other object) to popover simply us [NSKeyValueCoding](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/) setValue function

```
sortingPopoverController.setValue(array, forKey: "array")
```

To get its value back on any delegate method or wherever you need it, use valueForKey method and cast the returning value to your array type

```
sortingPopoverController.valueForKey("array") as! [ArrayOfSomething]
```

Comment: @zellb....i have added my findings...it is not working yet..Please see below............... sortingPopoverController.setValue(properties, forKey: "properties") and in sorting controller....i have added [ sortProperties = SortingPopoverController.valueForKey("properties") as! [Property]]

Comment: In sorting controller you need to get values as `sortProperties = self.valueForKey("properties") as! [Property]] `